# Prevent parent control binding child repeater

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a user control with a repeater on it that's using a sorted list as it's datasource. I noticed that the list gets databound to the repeater even if I don't call databind which means there is probably a parent control calling databind on it's children. The problem is, if I don't call databind, the list won't bind in the order it's sorted. If I do call databind, the list gets bound twice, once out of order and once sorted properly.

I've tried binding it as late as possible by overriding the page prerender event but still get the same result. Is there a way to prevent the parent from calling databind so I can call it once myself? Note I am developing a custom web part inside Kentico CMS so I'm not sure where the parent is that's calling Databind.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a boolean "DataBindByDefault" property on the repeater that controls whether or not it calls it's own DataBind method during the Init even in the page life cycle.

There's more information here:
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/CMSRepeater